# Not increasing loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, auto-increment

I want to calculate some descriptive statistics for each column in my database but when I enter this code, it stays in the first column. What should I do to increase the column?

```
Stat_Desc =function(x)
{
k<-ncol(x)
for(i in 1:k)
{
if(is.numeric(x[,i])| is.integer(x[,i]))
{}
else
{}
}
}
```

Comment: You don't need `is.integer` since `is.numeric` returns `TRUE` for integer vectors too.

Comment: Thank you Sven, I deleted that part but still doesn't work. It stays on the first column and doesn't calculate what I ask for the next ones...

Comment: The code in your example doesn't produce any output.

Comment: I added some `print` and used a data.frame as x. Output didn't show any problems. I suppose you should give the acutal data you input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you can tell your code doesn't increment when it doesn't produce any output.

Taking a logical step, if you just want to test if each column is a number you can:

```
sapply(x, is.integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Instead of putting a **print** I wrote a **return**, thats why the code didn't increment.
Thanks everyone anyway!